# Problema na declaração da variável 'name' javascript

Tags: javascript, declaração-de-variável, convenções-de-nome

Alguém pode me explicar qual é o problema da palavra 'name' no JavaScript?

O resultado do  primeiro  código vai dizer que a variável nome é um objeto e que name é uma string, sendo que a diferença(aparentemente) das variáveis é apenas a nomeação.

```
<script>
    var name = ["Henrique"];
    var nome = ["Henrique"];
    document.write("Tipo da variável nome " + typeof(nome));
    document.write('</br>');
    document.write("Tipo da variável name " + typeof(name));
</script>
```

Quando coloco o código dentro de uma IIFE o resultado será objeto para as duas.

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var name = ["Henrique"];
        var nome = ["Henrique"];
        document.write("Tipo da variável nome " + typeof(nome));
        document.write('</br>');
        document.write("Tipo da variável name " + typeof(name));
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: `name` é uma variável reservada do JavaScript. Se testar em seu console, verá que existe mesmo sem declará-la, eu não sei a necessidade dela.

No exemplo de baixo funciona pois você está declarando a variável `name` em um escopo isolado, sendo assim ela só irá existir dentro do seu bloco function() {}. Basicamente você terá uma name que está no escopo acima (no caso a reservada do javascript) e outra name dentro do escopo da função anônima que você criou.

Comment: Wallace, poste como resposta :) Só não é exatamente uma palavra reservada, é uma variável global disponível nos browsers (`window.name`).

Answer (score 0):

Como já dito nos comentários, `name`, assim como outras, é uma variável que já existe no objeto `window` do JavaScript, por isso, o problema, porém, ao cria-la em um contexto diferente, dentro de uma função, por exemplo, esse problema não ocorre

Basicamente, ao faz `var teste` estará criando uma variável no contexto que estiver sendo executado, seja o objeto window ou função, `let teste` e `const teste` declaram a variável no escopo do bloco, se for declarado apenas `teste` a variável será declarada no escopo de window, independentemente de onde o código for executado:

```js
var teste1 = 'teste1';
let teste2 = 'teste2';
const teste3 = 'teste3';

!function(){
  let teste4 = 'teste4';
  teste5 = 'teste5';
}()

console.log(window.teste1); //teste1
console.log(window.teste2); //undefined
console.log(window.teste3); //undefined
console.log(window.teste4); //undefined
console.log(window.teste5); //teste5
```

Se quiser saber quais são as variáveis globais "reservadas" pelo javascript:

```js
//window === this => true 
console.log(this);
```